# Tkinter: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, tkinter

i was trying to make a library with tkinter in python:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Screen():
    def make_window(self, width: int=None, height: int=None, title: str=None) -> int:
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.title = title
        new_window = tk.Tk()
        if width or height is not None:
            new_window.geometry(width + "x" + height)

win = Screen()
win.make_window()
```

it works fine and i get this nice little window:
[image]

but if i do this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Screen():
    def make_window(self, width: int=None, height: int=None, title: str=None) -> int:
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.title = title
        global new_window
        new_window = tk.Tk()
        if width or height is not None:
            new_window.geometry(width + "x" + height)
    def mainloop(self) -> None:
        new_window.mainloop()

win = Screen()
win.make_window(500, 500)
win.mainloop()
```

I get the error:

```
c:/Users/???/D
esktop/Leahnn Files/Python Projects/library/lib.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/????/Desktop/Leahnn Files/Python Projects/library/lib.py", line 16, in <module>
    win.make_window(500, 500)
  File "c:/Users/???/Desktop/Leahnn Files/Python Projects/library/lib.py", line 11, in make_window
    new_window.geometry(width + "x" + height)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Is there any way to convert the "int" to a "str" data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) ("f-string")

```
new_window.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
```

Comment: I had to go look up the tkinter doc to see for myself that it takes the geometry as a string instead of as two ints.  That's the most insane API I have ever seen.

Comment: @Samwise: It's due to the fact that the geometry function has its roots in the X11 windowing system. It's actually a very nice and concise way to specify both the dimensions and location of the window in a single string.

Comment: If they were going for retro charm and conciseness, they should have made you pack the width and height into a single 32 bit int, the cowards.

Comment: @Samwise: they weren't going for retro charm or conciseness. They were just using a format that was very common back when tk was first developed. tk has been around a very long time, and there's no reason to change this one small feature that already works perfectly well as-is. Plus, I'm reasonably certain that part of the design goal was to be able to set the geometry from a command line, and this meets that goal quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

That's happening because the width and height variables are integers and "x" is a string. You can't concatenate (or add) an integer and a string. Instead do this -

```
new_window.geometry(str(width) + "x" + str(height))
```

The `str()` function is used to convert int to str data type.

Comment: this worked fine, but the f-string one worked better. Thank you for answering though.

Comment: Yeah, f-strings are faster and have shorter syntax.